# How to retrieve express session cookie for next request (node script)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, cookies, express

I am using angular 1.2.23, and a nodejs server.

I have an authentification based on express-session 1.9.3.

Here are my options given to express

```
return {
    name: 'session',
    secret: signatureKey,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: getEnvName() === 'production',
        maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
};
```

I need to do a nodejs script, that will auth and fetch data for each users.

Operation should be like this

- for each users

  - POST request (Login, it will also create a session)
  - GET request (data)
  - GET request (logout)

The first request create the session, and returned a user item.
The second request has a middleware, which required to have a valid http cookie.

I am trying to find a way to get and send back the cookie for the second request, I can't find any documentation.

I accept any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

whould you use the express-session?

I had the same problem and have no idea by the document

only the first request will response cookie

when requested the cookie  store in mongodb expires modified

but the cookie in Browser(responsed) never change untill it's expired then will get a new cookie

so different to asp.net,jee ...

i edit the express-session code too solve the question

"version": "1.11.3"

express-session/index.js

find string "shouldSetCookie"

old code

```
 if (!shouldSetCookie(req)) {
    return;
  }
 setcookie(res, name, req.sessionID, secrets[0], cookie.data);
```

just  delete "restun",the every request will get cookie with new expires

new code
     if (!shouldSetCookie(req)) {
     }
     setcookie(res, name, req.sessionID, secrets[0], cookie.data);

in this way  you can edit the cookie and setcookie